# Image uploader messes up copy/paste function

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader

Clicking outside the image upload entry box to close it kills paste function.

System info: FF 39.0 & Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit) on Mac OSX

Explanation:

Occasionally when I'm using the image uploader to *link* to images on the web, I will be unable to paste the URL into the entry field or into the general text entry area.

The easiest way I've found to repro this is:

1. Go to a question/answer entry field.
2. Click on the uploader button.
3. Click outside the area of the uploader window (closes the window).
4. Try to use the paste shortcut in the answer entry area (doesn't work).
5. Click on the uploader button.
6. Click on the "You can also provide a link from the web." text to reveal the input box.
7. Try to use the paste shortcut (doesn't work).
8. Cry with frustration.
9. Click on "cancel".
10. Click on the "You can also provide a link from the web." text to reveal the input box again (still doesn't work).
11. Cry some more.

It seems the current "fix" is to use the x in the upper right corner to close the dialogue box and the paste function returns but I swear (in my frustrated tear-fogged brain) that there have been times this did not "fix" it but I can't repro that now.

Also, the system is clearly *trying* to paste... the edit menu flashes the way it usually does when you paste something, it's just that the content of the paste never appears... or it's in some other universe.

Comment: +1 Let me cry some more too...

Comment: yup; definitely repro that; very odd; I'll see what's happening...

Comment: ah, yes; I see; we don't call `disablePasteHandling` in the one case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build (at time of writing, current is 2015.8.3.3627 - so something *above* that).

Comment: Confirmed! Seems to be fixed. Thanks for that! No more tears for me... because of this, anyway :D

Comment: The fix seems to have missed at least one edge case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266523/uploading-an-image-from-the-web-can-leave-paste-broken-in-editor