# Uploading an image from the web can leave paste broken in editor

Tags: bug, editor, uploader

While reuploading a bunch of [old ImageShack images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising) to imgur, I noticed something funny: sometimes, after uploading an image from the web, I would no longer be able to paste anything into the edit box.  A bit more investigation revealed that the following steps are needed to reproduce this bug:

1. In the SE post editor, click the button to upload an image.
2. In the image upload dialog, click "You can also provide a link from the web."
3. Make sure the URL input box has the focus, and then close the dialog by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

   Alternatively, on Firefox, type or paste an image URL into the text box and submit the form by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  (This  does not seem to trigger the bug on Chrome; thanks, Chris Jester-Young.)

   Either way, the bug will *not* be triggered if you close the dialog by clicking something outside the URL input box, like the submit button or the close button.
4. Once back in the Markdown editor, try pasting something into the edit box.  Nothing will happen.
5. Reopening and closing the image upload dialog will make paste work again.

Apparently, what happens is that the image upload dialog installs its own paste event handler onto the `<body>` element, in order to let you paste images into the dialog to upload them.  This handler *should* be removed when the dialog closes, but the steps above break this, leaving the handler in place.

Why?  Well, it turns out that the dialog itself removes the paste event handler when the URL entry box gains focus (so that you can paste an URL into it, of course), and *adds it back* when the box loses focus.  But if you submit the upload form *while the URL entry box still has focus*, then the blur event handler on the box runs only *after* the dialog has closed.  Thus, the sequence of events (no pun intended) runs like this:

1. Open upload dialog.  Paste event handler is added.
2. URL entry box gets focus.  Paste event handler is removed.
3. Close upload dialog by pressing Esc.  Paste event handler is (again, redundantly) removed.
4. URL entry box loses focus as it disappears from the page.  Paste event handler is added back.  (Oops!)

How do we fix this?  Well, I see a bunch of ways:

- Have the code that closes the popup remove the `blur` event handler from the URL input, so that it cannot run any more, before removing the popup from the DOM.
- Have the `blur` event handler itself check a flag to see if we've already closed the dialog, and if so, not add back the `paste` handler on `<body>`.
- Have the `paste` handler itself check if the upload dialog is present, and if not, do nothing and let the event propagate.

Any of these should work.  Heck, you could implement all of them, just to make sure. :)

Comment: Up and down arrows also stop working. I guess this might be related.

Comment: @DavidPostill: That's odd, I can't seem to repro that one. It does sound like there might be a left-over keypress / keydown handler too. (And, in fact, there *is* one. It *should* only trigger on the escape key, but maybe there's some kind of a bug there too. BTW, what browser version are you using?)

Comment: I can't always repro it either. And I'm not sure if it's inserting images that triggers it. It might be selecting text and inserting a hyperlink. I do both of them a lot. It's definately one of the other (or both). Firefox 40 on Windows. Next time I see it I will let you know for sure which one it was.

Comment: OK. It's different bug when adding hyperlinks. To repro select some text, press ctrl+l, paste hyperlink, press enter. Now up and down arrow keys don't work. Maybe you can fix that in SOUP as well (I'm a big fan of SOUP) ;)

Comment: Switching to a different tab and back fixes the hyperlink bug if that helps.

Comment: @DavidPostill: OK, I can repro it now. Just pressing Ctrl+L and then Esc seems to be enough to trigger it. And just un-focusing the textarea seems to fix it, which unfortunately also makes it annoying to debug. :(

Comment: @DavidPostill: I still have *absolutely no idea* what's causing the arrow key bug, and I'm starting to suspect it's a bug in Firefox. But I did at least find [an earlier report of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264307/down-arrow-key-wont-work-after-using-the-hyperlink-button).

Comment: I **knew** there was a bug report - I just couldn't find it ... :/

Comment: I can't reproduce this (I submitted the URL by pressing Enter, and was able to paste). I'm using Chrome 45.0.2454.101 on OS X 10.10.5. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Firefox 41.0 / Ubuntu. I just tested this on Chromium 45.0.2454.85, and can repro this bug there by closing the upload dialog using the Esc key while the URL input box has focus, but *not* by pressing Enter. Not sure why, although I suspect some event sequencing difference between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Can reproduce this with Iceweasel (firefox) 38.5.0esr-1~deb7u2 on Debian 7.9 (wheezy). Happens loads of times.

Comment: To those regularly encountering this, it may be helpful to note that the information presented here also inspired a workaround: If you encounter this bug, paste functionality can be restored by opening the Upload Image popup _again_ and then closing it. That'll set the input handlers back to a sane state.

Comment: So, 2 years later this still happens. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306323/sometimes-i-cant-paste-into-the-edit-box

Answer (score 3):

What I came up with for the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script is this ugly hack:

```js
$('#content').on('paste', function () {
    if ( $('.modal-dropzone').length > 0 ) return;
    ( $._data( document.body, 'events' ).paste || [] ).forEach( function ( h ) {
        if ( ! /\.modal-dropzone/.test( h.handler.toString() ) ) return;
        $('body').off( 'paste', h.handler );
    } );
} );
```

For those not some familiar with the internals of jQuery, what this code does is catch paste events just *before* they reach the `<body>` and the upload dialog's event handler.  It then checks if the upload dialog seems to be present, and if not, digs into the guts of jQuery via `$._data()` to see if there are any paste event handlers defined for `<body>`.  If there are, it then double-checks that they really look like the upload dialog handler (by looking for a specific class name in their source code) and, if so, removes them just before they can fire.  (This should *hopefully* be a bit safer than just indiscriminately nuking all paste event handlers on `<body>`.)

Anyway, yeah, this is ugly even by SOUP standards. ;-)  I'd really like to see this fixed properly instead.  But until then, it's in SOUP as of the just released v1.38.

Comment: The `popupClose` event is a custom event we use for our popup system that fires when you click outside of the popup (it can also fire in other circumstances, such as hitting Esc, but for the purposes of our image uploader, that's the main place where it fires, since the image uploader has its own custom Esc handler).