# Sometimes I can't paste into the edit box

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

When writing a question or answer, I usually include a couple of links to outside resources. When I do the following:

1. Insert an image using 'Insert image/provide a link from the web'. Paste hyperlink into the dialog. Dialog closes. [image: Test image]
2. Insert a hyperlink into the edit box.  [test link](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/small-bodies/2014mu69-occultation-20170717.html)

step 2 fails: I can't paste anything into the Hyperlink dialog box. From that point on, I can't past into the answer box either. I have to post the answer, then click Edit, then I can paste again.

This happened when writing this question. In the edit history you should be able to see 2 revisions, where the first revision has an incomplete hyperlink (2).

OSX 10.10.5/Firefox 56.0 (I've also seen this on Windows 7/Firefox)

Comment: I think you need to include more information about Step 1: **HOW** do you "insert an image"? If it's using the browser's cut-and-paste feature (meaning, the "Copy image" context-menu option), then that part of the process may be involved in triggering whatever issue you're seeing.

Comment: Actually, it seems that image copy-and-paste doesn't work in Stack Exchange answer boxes, so I guess #neeeeevermind about that. But it would still be helpful to have more detail about the steps, along with what browser/OS you're using. So far I can't seem to reproduce, in Linux Chrome 64.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! [That other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266523/uploading-an-image-from-the-web-can-leave-paste-broken-in-editor) (the one this is a duplicate of) provides extensive information about why this happens, which allowed me to reproduce it. It also gave me hints about a workaround.

You can read the info there about how/why this happens, but the important thing is that the Upload Image popup does some weird things with input handlers (specifically, paste handlers), which can break the input processing for the rest of the page. So, the "fix", when this happens, is to open the Image Upload popup *again*, and then close it. That seems to repair paste functionality on the rest of the page, in my testing.